# Create program to display current date and time

Tags: javascript

Help! I'm new to Javascript and I need to create a program that displays the current date and time in this format:
Current Date: November 16, 2013 (full name format)
Current Time: hh:mm:ss PM (12-hour clock format with AM/PM)

I am building a webpage for a friend and I'm kinda lost :/ I would appreciate any help very much. Thank you!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kRL7P/ <- now figure out how to format that date, should take you about ten minutes with Google ?

Comment: Have a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cd9w2te4(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: Read up on the DateTime object, or you could use an existing js date/time library like http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method date to get the current date, `new Date()` then use some if else blocks to change its visibility.

The basic code is as

```
var date = "Date is: ";

var newDate = new Date(); // get the method

date += (newDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/"; // add 1 to the result and a backslash
date += newDate.getDate() + "/"; // get today's date and a backslash
date += newDate.getFullYear(); // get the full year (2013)

document.write(date); // write this to the document
```

You can add some If else blocks as

```
if(month == "1") {
  month = "January";
}
```

You need to work out with the API and style it, no API can do every thing for you. You need to add some code to it to make it work for you!

Good luck.

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/k63PE/ fiddle for this